# Getting maximum value from array in C++ using pointer

Tags: c++, arrays

I am gonna want maximum value from the array using a pointer. But I am not getting the accurate value. Please, help.

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;
int main()
{
    int* largest;
    int a[5]={4,5,666,7,8};
    largest=a;
    for(int i=1; i<5; i++)
    {
        if(*largest<*(largest+i))
        {
            *largest=*(largest+i);
            largest=largest+i;
        }
    }
    cout<<*largest;

}
```

I am getting 7339544 as an output rather than 666. I don't know what I am doing wrong.

Comment: Use your debugger! Single step through the program and see what the value of `largest` (and other variables) is at different points. A debugger is an essential tool for a programmer. A programmer who doesn't use their debugger is like a carpenter that won't use a... whatever carpenters use. A hammer I guess? I don't know much about carpentry.

Comment: Btw: Use standard containers, iterators and algorithms whenever possible. They avoid lots of nasty issues. Raw pointers and arrays have a smell in c++ and are prone to bugs.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You're indexing outside the array, causing undefined behaviour.

You're doing this

```
largest
  |
  v
| 4 | 5 | 666 | 7 | 8 |
      ^
      |
   largest + 1
```

then

```
    largest
      |
      v
| 5 | 5 | 666 | 7 | 8 |
                ^
                |
           largest + 2
```

then

```
             largest
                |
                v
| 5 | 7 | 666 | 7 | 8 |    outside
                             ^
                             |
                        largest + 3
```

(Note that you're also modifying the array, which you shouldn't.)

The main problem is that you're trying to use `largest` for three purposes simultaneously:

- iterating,
- storing the largest value,
- storing the position of the largest value.

It should only point to the largest array element; you should only change its value, not the value of the element it points to.

```
int main()
{
    const int a[5] = {4, 5, 666, 7, 8};
    const int* largest = a;
    for (int i = 1; i < 5; i++)
    {
        if (*largest < a[i])
        {
            largest = &a[i];
        }
    }
    cout << *largest;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <time.h>

int generateNumber(int lower_limit, int upper_limit);
void fillArr(int *arr, unsigned int arrSize, int lower_limit, int upper_limit);
void printElementsArr(int *arr, unsigned int arrSize);
int maxElementArr(int *arr, unsigned int arrSize);

int main()
{
    char expression;
    int l_l, u_l;
    int arrSize;


do{

srand(time(0)); 

printf("Insert array size:\n");
scanf("%d", &arrSize);

if(arrSize < 0){
    while (arrSize<0){
        printf("Insert positive array size:\n");
        scanf("%d", &arrSize);
    }
}

int array[arrSize];

printf("Insert lower limit of an array:\n");
scanf("%d", &l_l);

printf("Insert upper limit of an array:\n");
scanf("%d", &u_l);

while(u_l<l_l){
    
    printf("the upper limit (%d) is smaller then the lower limit (%d), set a new upper limit of an array: ",u_l,l_l);
    scanf("%d",&u_l);
}

fillArr(array, arrSize, l_l, u_l);
printElementsArr(array, arrSize);
maxElementArr(array, arrSize);

getchar();
printf("If you want to end the program insert 'n' else insert any key: ");
scanf("%c",&expression);


}while(expression != 'n');

}
//---------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------


int generateNumber(int lower_limit, int upper_limit){
    
    return rand() % (upper_limit-lower_limit)+lower_limit;
}

void fillArr(int *arr, unsigned int arrSize, int lower_limit, int upper_limit){
    
    int i = 0;
    
    for (i; i < arrSize; i++){
        
        *(arr+i)= generateNumber(lower_limit, upper_limit);
    }
    
}

void printElementsArr(int *arr, unsigned int arrSize){
    
    int i = 0;
    printf("\n");
    
    for (i; i < arrSize; i++){
        
        printf("%d.element of an array: %d\n" ,i+1, *(arr+i));
        
    }
    
}


int maxElementArr(int *arr, unsigned int arrSize){
    
    int i = 1, max= *arr;
    
    for(i; i<arrSize; i++){
        if(max < *(arr+i)){
            max = *(arr+i);
        }
        
    }
    
    printf("\nThe max element of an array is: %d\n",max);
}
```

Because this code consists of multiple parts I created each independent functions for each problem a then I initially called them in my main function except the one that generates numbers. I used that one in the function where it fills the array with the numbers.
I created the function for generating a random numbers, filling an array with the numbers and printing every each element(number) of an array.
The reason I created the random number generator is because it is more dynamic than static array with pre-defined numbers and size of an array.
Also before the fill and print functions are called, first I ask the user for an array size and if the array size is lower than 0 therefore it will ask the user to insert a positive number and a I also ask user for a lower and an upper limit of an array and if the upper limit is lower than the lower limit a question with the information that the upper limit is lower than the upper one  will pop-up over and over again with the option to insert a new upper limit unless the user inserts a number that is higher than the lower limit.
Also, the whole program is in loop with the question in the end if they want to end the program.

Answer (score -1):

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;
int main()
{
    int* largest;
    int a[5]={4,5,666,7,8};
    largest=a;
    for(int i=1; i<5; i++)
    {
       if(*largest < a[i])
    {
        largest = &a[i];// This works perfectly
       //largest = largest+i; There is no meaning of this line
    }
    }
    cout<<*largest;

}
```

Comment: The expected result is `largest == &a[2]` and `a[0] == 4`, not `*largest == a[2]` and `a[0] == 666`.